# Get rid of group icon without hiding column

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, reporting

We have a report that gets populated by stored procedure. In the datatable we have a column "RowType" which is set to either 1, 2 or 3. 
1 : Normal data row
2 : Important data row (In the picture this is the 1st row of data, the bold one)
3 : Devider rows. These are the rows with which we are having some issues. They are the two rows at the bottom of the image with the grey background.

The entire report is styled by either the "RowType" value or some of the other items in the datatable.
**The Problem:**
We have decided to change our report to make use of grouping, instead of drill down reports. I'm not going to go into the reasons for this decision. 
The grouped rows each have a little icon to the left of it (Generated by report server) which is used to view the details of that row.(Sorry about that, pretty sure you know all this).
I have coded the "expand icon" to be hidden on rows that does not have detailed/grouped data, but that left me with the problem that the grey column would now also be hidden which leaves me with a **blank white space**  instead of the grey cell.
Obviously this makes my report look horrible. Is there any way to remove the icon for a particular row without setting the Hidden property to True?

If not, is there a way to have the report row fill the background of a hidden cell with a defined colour?

The bottom right corner contains an example of what it looks like when one of the grey cells have been hidden. The bottom left shows the report with the unwanted icons in the grey cells
[image: The image mentioned.]

Comment: 1.) When you say "I have coded the expand icon to be hidden..." Are you using the built-in toggle feature with in SSRS grouping or is it a custom element? 2.) Are you hiding the image or the textbox that the image is in? If your code is hiding the textbox, can you create another textbox with a gray background that is hidden/shown when the show/hide for the expand icon is inversed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could cut your current textbox out (the one with the +- icon, then add a rectangle from the toolbox into that cell, then paste your textbox back in.  That way the texbox becomes a child of the rectangle.  Then you can move your grey formatting to the rectangle, which will never be hidden.